# Passing Java ArrayList variable index to JavaScript via JXBrowser

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, jxbrowser

I have two classes in my project. One is the main class called Test that contains all of the functions of the code.
It also has multiple Array lists defined in it, and I want to use two of those and put their values in JavaScript using the JXBrowser library.
Please take a look at the place where I added a comment.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is use Google Maps in the Java class using JavaScript by the JXBrowser library and add multiple markers by taking the longitude and latitude from the main class and adding them within the JavaScript code.

```
final Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Map");
    frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(900, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    browser.loadHTML("<html>\n"
            + "    <head>\n"
            + "   <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\"/>\n"
            + "   <style type=\"text/css\">\n"
            + "       html { height: 100% }\n"
            + "       body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }\n"
            + "       #map-canvas { height: 100% }\n"
            + "   </style>\n"
            + "   <script type=\"text/javascript\"\n"
            + "           src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC-6h0sjJTfO2Kf5JxJYKdD-DwHwPHKVZI&sensor=false\"></script>\n"
            + "   <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
            + "     var map;\n"
            + "     function initialize() {\n"
            + "       var mapOptions = {\n"
            + "         center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.209331, 16.381302),\n"
            + "         zoom: 4\n"
            + "       };\n"
            + "      var marker, i;\n"
//This is where the problem is and what i'm trying to do.
            + "      for (i = 0; i < Test.keywordIndex.getsize() ; i++) {\n" 
            + "         marker = new google.maps.Marker({\n"
            + "         position: new  google.maps.LatLng(Test.latitude.get(Test.keywordIndex.get(i), Test.longitude.get(Test.keywordIndex.get(i),\n"
            + "         map: map\n"
            + "       });\n"
            + "     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({\n"
            + "    position:  new google.maps.LatLng(48.209331, 16.381302),\n"
            + "    map: map,\n"
            + "    title: 'Hello World!'\n"
            + "});"
            + "     }\n"
            + "     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);\n"
            + "\n"
            + "   </script>\n"
            + "</head>\n"
            + "<body>\n"
            + "<div id=\"map-canvas\"></div>");
```

I have the idea but not sure about the execution of the code itself

Comment: you should run it first and see if you get desired result.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking this question if I didn't run it and didn't get results

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser will support ArrayList in [JavaScript-Java Bridge](http://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/samples#TOC-JavaScript-Java-Bridge) in 6.0 version that is going to be released in October-November 2015.

Comment: @Validimir What about simple arrays based on some object? I can't get Arrays.isArray(passedToJs) to work. Nor would passedToJs.splice !== undefined ... How do I pass a java array to making it a valid javascript array ?